# Dynamically bind control to object in Mudblazor page

Tags: file-upload, mudblazor, dynamic-controls

I have a form that upload multiple files and their associated meta data. I would like to dynamically add metadata to each file depending on how many files are selected for upload.

I render a list of Title, Description and Document Type controls based on the amount of files selected.

I can link the document title to the object model but not the description or type. I would really appreciate any assistance.

a Link to the solution is : https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GamouRctzOwKzYVn